# Using Promises to defer continuation within a forEach loop

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

My goal with the below is to:

- Capture a list of resolutions
- Scan through each of them (in order) to find the first one that results in a successful stream

To test this, I have `testVideoPresence`:

```
var testCounter = 0;
function testVideoPresence(videoElement) {
    testCounter++;
    if (testCounter >= 5) {
        testCounter = 0;
        return false;
    }
    if (!videoElement.videoWidth || videoElement.videoWidth < 10) { // check to prevent 2x2 issue
        setTimeout(function() {
            testVideoPresence(videoElement); // try again
        }, 500);
    } else if (video.videoWidth * video.videoHeight > 0) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm using a `setTimeout` to recurse at most 5 times.  This is where things get tricky:

```
 resolutionTestBuilder.buildTests().then(function (resolutionTests) {
        // at this point, I have a set of resolutions that I want to try
        resolutionTests.forEach(function (resolutionTest) {
            // then I want to iterate over all of them until I find one that works
            performTest(resolutionTest).then(function (result) {
                video.srcObject = result.mediaStream; // start streaming to dom
                if (testVideoPresence(video)) { // here is the pain point - how do I await the result of this within the forEach?
                    // return the dimensions
                } else {
                    // continue scanning
                }
            }).catch(function (error) {
                logger.internalLog(error);
            });

            // wait to continue until we have our result

        });
    }).catch(function (error) {
        logger.internalLog(error);
    });

function performTest(currentTest) {
        return streamHelper.openStream(currentTest.device, currentTest.resolution).then(function(streamData) {
            return streamData;
        }).catch(function (error) {
            logger.internalLog(error);
        });;
    };

streamHelper.openStream = function (device, resolution) {
    var constraints = createVideoConstraints(device, resolution);
    logger.internalLog("openStream:" + resolution.label + ": " + resolution.width + "x" + resolution.height);
    return navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
        .then(function (mediaStream) {
            streamHelper.activeStream = mediaStream;
            return { stream: mediaStream, resolution: resolution, constraints: constraints };
            // video.srcObject = mediaStream; // push mediaStream into target element.  This triggers doScan.
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            if (error.name == "NotAllowedError") {
                return error.name;
            } else {
                return error;
            }
        });
 };
```

I'm trying to wait for the result within the `forEach` before continuing through the array of resolutions.  I know I can use some advanced techniques like async/await if I want to transpile - but I'm stuck with vanilla JS and promises / bluebird.js for now.  What are my options?  Disclaimer - I am new to promises so the above code could be very malformed.

**Update:**

Tests are defined in order of importance - so I do need `resolutionTests[0]` to resolve before `resolutionTests[1]`.

Comment: the question is: do you want the first of the resolutionTests that works to return the dimensions, or is it ok if `any` of the resolutionTests that work returns the dimensions - not matter which. The latter is simpler to implement because you can use `map` and `Promise.race`. The former is a bit more difficult but you'd likely use `reduce`. In neither case `forEach` is appropriate

Comment: @OvidiuDolha I want the first of the resolutionTests that works to return the dimensions - they're ordered from high to low and I'm looking for the max compatible resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order of trials isn't important, you can simply use a `map` combined with `Promise.race` to make sure the first promise of a list that resolves resolves the whole list. You also need to make sure your promises return other promises inside `then`.

```
resolutionTestBuilder.buildTests().then(function (resolutionTests) {
    return Promise.race(resolutionTests.map(function (resolutionTest) {
        return performTest(resolutionTest).then(function (result) {
            video.srcObject = result.mediaStream; // start streaming to dom
            return testVideoPresence(video);
        }).catch(function (error) {
            logger.internalLog(error);
        });
    }));
}).catch(function (error) {
    logger.internalLog(error);
});
```

This of course assumes that `testVideoPresence` does NOT resolve when you the dimensions are not available.

If the order of trial is important then a `reduce` approach might work.

This will basically result in a sequential application of the promises and the resulting promise will until all of them are resolved.

However, once the solution is found we attach it to the collector of the reduce so that further trials simply return that as well and avoid further tests (because by the time this is found the chain is already registered)

```
return resolutionTests.reduce(function(result, resolutionTest) {
    var nextPromise = result.intermPromise.then(function() {
        if (result.found) { // result will contain found whenver the first promise that resolves finds this
            return Promise.resolve(result.found);   // this simply makes sure that the promises registered after a result found will return it as well
        } else {
            return performTest(resolutionTest).then(function (result) {
                video.srcObject = result.mediaStream; // start streaming to dom
                return testVideoPresence(video).then(function(something) {
                    result.found = something;
                    return result.found;
                });
            }).catch(function (error) {
                logger.internalLog(error);
            });
        }
    );
    return { intermPromise: nextPromise, found: result.found };
}, { intermPromise: Promise.resolve() }); // start reduce with a result with no 'found' and a unit Promise
```

Comment: Thank you - though the order is important.  Looks like I answered your comment as you were writing this up - though this may be useful for future readers.

Comment: Added the other approach as an idea - it might contain some errors but the idea is you reduce the list of tries - which means all the promises will be chained together - then on the first one you find something you make sure the future ones are no longer trying

Comment: I get syntax error on `=>` - is there a way to use this with plain JS?

Comment: force of habit :) - `function() {` instead

Comment: +1 because this seems elegant, though I'm getting `result.intermPromise` is `undefined` on its second pass...  Is there a way I can contact you for some paid remote debugging to get past this? :)

Comment: darn, it was wrong return inside the reduce, we still need to return the same type throughout the reduce, i.e. an object with the current promise and the current found - code without es6 is quite difficult to manage :P - hope it works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144676/discussion-between-sb2055-and-ovidiu-dolha).

Answer (score 1):

At first , your testVideoPresence returns undefined. It wont work that way. May do:

```
function testVideoPresence(videoElement,callback,counter=0) {
 if(counter>10) callback(false);
    if (!videoElement.videoWidth || videoElement.videoWidth < 10) {
        setTimeout(testVideoPresence, 500,videoElement,callback,counter+1);
    } else if (video.videoWidth * video.videoHeight > 0) {
         callback(true);
    }
}
```

SO you can do:

```
testVideoPresence(el, console.log);
```

Now to the forEach. You cannot yield the forEach in any way. However you could write your own recursive forEach:

```
(function forEach(el,index) {
  if(index>=el.length) return false;

  performTest(el[index]).then(function (result) {
       video.srcObject = result.mediaStream; // start streaming to dom

       testVideoPresence(video,function(success){
           if(!success) return alert("NOO!");
           //do sth
           //proceed
          setTimeout(forEach,0,el,index+1);
        });
  }).catch(function (error) {
          logger.internalLog(error);
 });
})(resolutionTests,0);//start with our element at index 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function raceSequential(fns) {
    if(!fns.length) {
        return Promise.resolve();
    }
    return fns.slice(1)
        .reduce(function(p, c) { 
            return p.catch(c);
        }, fns[0]());
}

// "Resolution tests"
var t1 = function() { return new Promise(function(_, reject) { setTimeout(() => reject('t1'), 1000); })};
var t2 = function() { return new Promise(function(resolve) { setTimeout(() => resolve('t2'), 1000); })};
var t3 = function() { return new Promise(function(resolve) { setTimeout(() => resolve('t3'), 1000); })};

var prom = raceSequential([t1, t2, t3])
    .then(function(result) { console.log('first successful result: ' + result); });
```

Scanning your code indicates you have other async-related problems.

Comment: I should have specified this - but the order is important.  If the first test works, I prefer it over any following items in the array of tests.

Comment: Do you want to run them in sequence or continue to attempt parallelization?

Comment: I need them to run sequentially.